# react-native bundle images path

Tags: react-native

I'm creating main.jsbundle for creating simulator build to submit to facebook for app review.

I'm making jsbundle and using jsbundle, images are not shown.

I think there'a issue when I make main.jsbundle with below command

```
react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

All of my images are created again in ios/assets/.

My Images folder are in src/images. So I have double images. so I thought I needed to revise the path for asset.

so I tried to do it with below code

```
react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest src/images
```

but all of my images are created in src/images/asset/src/images/

how can I link jsbundle with current image path?

Answer (score 2):

First command should work fine. Once the images are copied to your newly created assets folder, you have to add the reference of that folder in your Xcode project. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Open your project in Xcode.
2. Right click on the name of your project being displayed on the left side bar.
3. Select the option Add Files to .
4. A dialog will appear asking you to give the location of file / folder you want to add. Select your newly created assets folder here. Select "create folder references" option from the options displayed in the dialog.
5. Click Add.

Thats' it now you have created folder reference in your Xcode project, just build your project and run. It should work fine.

Comment: this is the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first command is the correct command for creating bundle for iOS.

```
react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

After running this command you can create your archive from Xcode.

Comment: but there's error message 
Could not find image file:///Users/kimkwanhui/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1A958972-4857-4404-B0F1-17A1B6678588/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2B808BBC-EC31-4242-ACE6-03BC118867ED/BUZZi.app/assets/src/images/FrontTextFieldPNG.png

Comment: for some reason, simulator can't detect images

Answer (score 0):

(For testing)You'll need to create an IPA Go to Xcode>Product>archive 
and then you can use diawi.com/fastlane for testing purpose

if you need in more detail follow below article

And for publishing on app store
You can't directly publish an bundle file to app store

You can follow this article for apple app store process
[deploying-react-native-apps-to-app-store-and-play-market](https://apiko.com/blog/deploying-react-native-apps-to-app-store-and-play-market/)

Comment: I already have archive file and my app is published already. My purpose is to submit simulator build for facebook app review. Have you done this before?

Comment: Okay You can delete all these images which are recreated when you create a bundle as these are like thumbnails(duplicate image resources) deleting them won't impact anything and then you can publish